# Firebase read/write permission for certain users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a family, **A, b, c, d**, and **A** is the leader. We have an intruder, **E**. We only want **b, c, d** to read/write A's data.

**ALL OF THESE letters (b, c d,...) will be the UID's**

Here is what I have so far:

**Everyone** is authenticated with email. People send requests to **A** to be allowed in his group. If he accepts, they can read/write to his.

Design for database Firebase

```
{
  "Leaders" : {
    "A" : {
      "ALLOWED" : {
        "b" : 0,
        "c" : 0,
        "d" : 0
      },
      "DATA" : {
        "blah blah1" : "content writable by bcd",
        "blah blah2" : "content writable by bcd"
      },
      "REQUESTS" : {
        "E" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can use CRUD to move the **b, c, d** but how do I make the rules so that it follows that only people in the **ALLOWED** can read/write data for each leader?

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
    "Leaders":{
    ".write": "$uid == ????"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, ah! Sorry, I didnt know we could do this, will update in a min

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be a matter of checking if the node exists under the current leader:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Leaders":{
      "$leaderuid": {
         ".write": "$leaderuid == auth.uid",
         "DATA": {
           ".write": "data.parent().child('ALLOWED').child(auth.uid).exists()"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Things I changed:

- Remove the top-level read/write rules. Otherwise any authenticated user can read/write all data and you can never take that permission away at a lower level anymore.
- The leader can write their entire node. I use `auth.uid` here as described in the [documentation on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable).
- A user can only write under `DATA` if their uid exists in the `ALLOWED` node.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what "$leaderuid" means? Thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: I mean, when you have $leaderuid$ { }, what is this is the context?

Comment: Also one more error occurs is that a ", )" is expected at the line with "DATA"

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo. Any key starting with a `$` is just a wildcard/variable. See the Firebase documentation to learn more about them: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read up a lot on it, but I am still unable to understand this. I will ask a new question as it is a general firebase question

Comment: Also if you dont mind elaborating, why have you used "data" instead of "DATA" in the last line?

Comment: `data` is one of the [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables), referring to the current node. I highly recommend reading the documentation on security rules as it will explain this and many more concepts better than I can do here.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Definitely will do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What if the data node was outside the current leader and data node will have a child -uid which we will tell which leader has posted this data. Then  How to restrict read permission for others users ? same type of question I have already posted it will be great if you can answerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539146/read-permissions-only-for-few-users