# $ variables in Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Recently [I asked a question about Firebase permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838578/firebase-read-write-permission-for-certain-users): Here is a JSON Tree of rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Leaders":{
      "$leaderuid": {
         ".write": "$leaderuid == auth.uid",
         "DATA": {
           ".write": "data.parent().child('ALLOWED').child(auth.uid).exists()"
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**The actual database**

```
    {
  "Leaders" : {
    "A" : {
      "ALLOWED" : {
        "b" : 0,
        "c" : 0,
        "d" : 0
      },
      "DATA" : {
        "blah blah1" : "content writable by bcd",
        "blah blah2" : "content writable by bcd"
      },
      "REQUESTS" : {
        "E" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would just like help understanding what `$leaderuid` means. I've read up on the docs and this is a temporary variable.

I have an idea, and please correct me or tell me if what I am thinking is accurate.

The temporary variable created `$leaderuid` is the authUID of the leader that was created?

Comment: its just a place holder for your dynamic keys under Leader node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ variable has whatever key the node has that you're under. So if you'd have the following structure:

```
{
  "Leaders" : {
    "A" : {
      ...
    },
    "B": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

When your security rules are evaluated under `A`, then `$leaderuid` will be `A`. But when the rules are evaluated under `B`, then `$leaderuid` will be `B`.

The name of the $ variable is unimportant. But since you seem to be keeping a list of leaders and you said you stored them under their UID, I named the variable `$leaderuid` in my previous answer.

This is covered in the [Firebase documentation on structuring data for securing user access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-structuring-db). Spending a few hours there and in the rest of the documentation, should answer a lot of questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this more. One question though. How will Firebase check if the first one is UID or the second or the third....? Essentially, does the $ variable create recursion where it checks all of the $leaderuids and checks if the current id matches any of them?

Comment: Rules are always evaluated in the context of an actual node in your JSON tree. When you use a variable in a rule (such as `$leaderuid == auth.uid`), the server searches up from that context node until it finds where you declared the variable and use that key. But to be honest, this is quite hard to explain and a lot easier to use when start playing with the rules simulator in the Database Console.